# What does the Ruby each method consist of?

Tags: ruby

Where can new rubyists find the inner code for the ruby each method? Or any ruby method at that.

With each I'm guessing it's using 'for loops' but I'd like to study it.

Comment: Look at the source code.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse the Ruby source code on Github: https://github.com/ruby/ruby. For the `Array#each` method, look in `array.c`. At the bottom of the file you can see method names being mapped to C functions. You can see the `each` method is mapped to `rb_ary_each()`:

```
rb_define_method(rb_cArray, "each", rb_ary_each, 0);
```

Then you can scroll up to find its implementation:

```
VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the cool things about ruby-doc.org is that you can hover your mouse over a method's documentation, and you'll see a "click to toggle source" message appear in the upper right corner along with a magnifying glass icon.  Clicking works as advertised.  Check it out with [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each).